# Packing data for multi - light fragment shader in OpenGL 4x

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I have a 3d renderer written in C++ and OpenGL 4.x I have a forward lighting system which works ok.But I think how to optimize it because I believe my bottleneck is the way I pack lights params on client side.

In fragment shader I have an array of Light structs like this:

```
 #define numLights 10;
 struct Light {
   int  lightType;
   vec4 position;
   vec4 ambient;
   vec4 diffuse;
   vec4 specular;

 };
uniform Light lights[numLights];
```

Let's say I have 10 lights in the scene ,so I have a method which fills the array above and sends it to the shader program:

```
  void LightCollector:: UpdateLights(const GLuint& program)const{
    size_t vecSize =_lights.size();
    for(size_t i = 0; i <vecSize; ++i) {
        if(!_lights[i]->lightDirty) continue;
        //  set struct array of each light props here
        std::string lt=std::string("lights[") + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i) + "].lightType";
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program,lt.c_str ),DIR_LIGHT);
                  ..............
                  ...................
                  ........................
                  ... the same goes for each Light prop in the struct

       _lights[i]->lightDirty=false;
    }
 }
```

As one can see I have to do string concatenations and number to string conversion which probably adds some overhead.
Is there a more efficient way to pass this data to shaders?

Comment: FYI: lights do not have ambient, diffuse, or specular colors. Unless you think that the sun gives off special "ambient" light...

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about. Every book about point light in OpenGL presents Ka, Kd, Ks ...   ;)

Comment: I think he means that there's a "lighting model" and the light gives off a colour, but the *material* has diffuse, specular properties.  Ambient is of course a fudge factor/approximation things like radiosity that you can apply in the material, or global environment.

Comment: To add to that, I have two sets of parameters: the Light (which has a colour) and a material.  You set the material once and then iterate the lights in the shader.

Comment: I have material props as well which I pass just once for material in use.The props in the Light struct are needed to tweak each light color in addition to material colors.I implement lighting model slightly differently than it is typically done in 3d graphics.Also , my question is a little bit different :)